# Rendering .map of object to change its properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops, onclick

I'm new to React js & React Native please help

so i have this data of partners

```
const [lessorPartners , setLessorPartners] = useState(null)
const dataPartnerBeforeFetch = [
    {id:1, name:"BFI" , img:"lessor1" , code:"PU77"},
    {id:2, name:"SMF" , img:"lessor2" , code:"TT38"},
    {id:3, name:"Adira" , img:"lessor3" , code:"PT74"},
    {id:4, name:"BFI" , img:"lessor1" , code:"PB63"},
    {id:5, name:"SMF" , img:"lessor2" , code:"BU42"},
    {id:6, name:"Adira" , img:"lessor3" , code:"AL39"}
  ]

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(dataPartnerBeforeFetch ){
      dataPartnerBeforeFetch.map(dataPartner=>{
        dataPartner.color = false
      })
      setLessorPartners(dataPartnerBeforeFetch)
    }
  },[dataPartnerBeforeFetch ])
```

I added color to its end if its true then it will turn transparent / false it will be orange

and I tried to loop it :
and render it all with these functions

```
  const renderingPartners = () => {
    return(
      lessorPartners.map(lessorPartner => {
        renderingPartner(lessorPartner)
      })
    )
  }

  const renderingPartner = (lessorPartner) =>{
    return(
    <div style={{backgroundColor: false ? 'orange' : 'transparent'}}
      onClick={()=>{
        onClickParter(lessorPartner);
      }}
    >
      <LessorPartner
        key = {lessorPartner.id}
        object = {lessorPartner}
      />
    </div>
    )
  }
```

and i tried to call renderingPartners() in my app .js like this

```
<div>
{ lessorPartners && renderingPartners()}
</div>
```

but no component returned, just empty and no error

the next idea is to change it's color on click with this function and re render the whole mapping

```
const onClickParter = (q) =>{
    q.color = !q.color
    let index = lessorPartners.indexOf(q);
    lessorPartners[index]= q
    setLessorPartners(lessorPartners)
    renderingPartners()
  }
```

just like radio button with list of lessor that i've tried to map

please help i've been stuck here for hours

Answer (score 0):

So map function returns a new array (also it returns a value so if you are specifying braces you have to explicitly write return). you should modify your first snippet like this:

```
let _dataPartnerBeforeFetch = dataPartnerBeforeFetch.map(dataPartner=>{
    return {
        ...dataPartner,
        color : false
    }
});
setLessorPartners(_dataPartnerBeforeFetch)
```

Similarly this snippet should be corrected like this:

```
lessorPartners.map(lessorPartner => renderingPartner(lessorPartner))
```

Edited:
Why the color change is not reflected?

Its almost always best to return a new array.

```
const onClickParter = (q) =>{
    let _lessorPartners = lessorPartners.filter(f=> !(f.indexOf(q) >= 0));
    _lessorPartners.push({
        ...q,
        color : !q.color
    });
    setLessorPartners(_lessorPartners);
    //renderingPartners();
    //we donot have to explicity call the function to enforce rerender because it's already binded by a state variable. So setting the state would do the trick.
}
```

Here filter returns a new copy of the array without the item in scope (reffered to as 'q'). Then you add a new object with the inverted color to the new array and set the state.

Comment: thank you now its rendering the component of individual partner but why can't i change the color ? eventho i change the color with setLessorPartners? On my onClickParter function, my console log shows right result

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: backgroundColor: false ? 'orange' : 'transparent' is not checking anything, maybe you can try backgroundColor: lessorPartner.color ?  'transparent' : 'orange'

Comment: it doesn't do anything , i think the problem lies on how I render it properties

Comment: Yep, it wont do anything because of false ? 'orange' : 'transparent'. false is a static boolean condition so the outcome will always be transparent.
So try and modify your code as suggested by @RodSar in his comment above.
that way you are specifying in the condition to render the div's bg color based off of the boolean value in the lessorPartner.color.